# how can i get a sign in/ Register plug in like fiverr.com's on WordPress

Tags: plugins, wordpress

Please have a look on fiverr.com's page. they have sign in/register buttons that pop up and darkens the page behind it.

Any suggestions for this functionality on Wordpress? I'd be happy to pay for a good plug in!

Comment: I'd like to make a recommendation, attempt to do this yourself first, or show that you have made an attempt at finding a solution first. You are not likely to get someone from SO to just solve your problem for you. Likewise, the way you worded this I thought it might be spam/advertising (e.g. immediately linking off site to check out a website). Perhaps create some screen captures to show the effect you are looking for? Also not sure if wordpress plugins would be considered "programming" or not. ;)

Comment: thanks for this, i'm very new to stack overflow and I've only recently started customising WordPress plug ins using PHP. I assumed there would be some customisation involved no matter what plug in I opted for. I have tried to find a solution, but to no avail. I guess I really wanted to know if it was doable using Wordpress/ PHP. I'll take what you've said on board and go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a reference - I do not use WordPress, but I am almost certain this functionality is in it somewhere. To answer at the heart of your question though using other means...

You can absolutely do this using CSS/jQuery/PHP. Here is a link to get you started on a tutorial. There is also a number of other tutorials for this with simple google searches.

https://codyhouse.co/gem/loginsignup-modal-window/

As for darkening the background, you should be able to do that using CSS/jQuery for the on-click/open events.

For a specific wordpress solution, I believe this might be what you are looking for but to be frank, I have very little experience with WP so can't confirm it is correct.

https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/tags/login-dialog

Best of luck!

Comment: This is extremely helpful! I will get on it now. Thank you! PS. I'll learn to use Stack properly going forward.

Comment: On that note, feel free to accept the answer if you feel it was correct (check box on the left) / rank it up. I would recommend briefly looking over the rules before posting next time as well ;). Welcome to the site!